# Get top best score in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have 2 tables:

```
user: id, name

score: id, user_id, point
```

Now I want to get 5 users name who have the best score but seem like it was wrong.

Here's my code:

```
public function getTop(){
        $top = DB::table('score')
            ->select('user_id', DB::raw('COUNT(point)'))
            ->groupBy('user_id')
            ->orderBy(DB::raw('COUNT(point)'), 'DESC')
            ->take(5)
            ->get();
        return view('home',compact('top'));
    }
```

Comment: What kind of results are you getting?

Comment: It returns the sum of point of each user of top 5. What I want is the highest score of each user and then choose the top 5 users

Comment: Instead of count() use max().

Comment: @forpas It's still wrong. It returned the highest point of each user successfully but top 5 is wrong

Comment: *It returned the highest point of each user successfully* then how can it be wrong? Did you change both count() to max()?

Comment: Oops sorry. Now it's true. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

In your case Database query makes more senses.

1. Database query to get top 5 user_id with total score.
2. Join users table with that result.

   ```
   $topResult = DB::table('users'
   )->join(DB::raw('(SELECT user_id, SUM(point) as score FROM score GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY SUM(point) LIMIT 5) as top_scorer'), function($join) {
       $join->on('top_scorer.user_id', '=','users.id');
   })
   ->select(['users.*', 'top_scorer.score']) //Select fields you need.
   ->orderBy('top_scorer.score')
   ->get();
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
DB::table('users')
    ->select(['users.id', DB::raw('MAX(sc.point) AS score')])
    ->join('score AS sc', 'sc.id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->groupBy('users.id')
    ->take(5)->get();
```